# Python : How to get the respective age and balance of the matching name?

Tags: python-3.x, list, indexing

**Objective**  A mini bank simulation using only python basics list,while loop,if else.

**Issues**  2. Search account. 
**Notes** I want my program to return the respective age and balance of the matching name.Thanks in advance.

```
print("""1. Add Account
2. Search Account"
3. Exit \n\n""")

name = []
age = []
balance = []

while True:

    choice = input("What is your choice ? : ")

    if choice == "1":

        name.append(input("Name : "))

        age.append(input("Age : "))

        balance.append(input("Balance : "))

        print("Account Registration Done\n\n")

    if choice == "2":

        y = input("What is your Account Name ? > : ") 

        if y in name:  # i want my program to return the respective age and balance of the matching name.
            print(name[0]) # Here is the issue and i don't know how to fix.Please Kindly enlighten me
            print(age[0])
            print(balance[0])

        else:
            print(
                f"Your name[{y}] have't registered yet.Please register first")

    if choice == "3":
        break
```

Comment: "*i want my program to return newly added account"* Is it like you always want the newly added account details or details of the account matching the name?

Comment: Details of the  account matching the name. Thank you so much for your comment.

Comment: Is it possible for you to update the question to make it clear? Already we have two answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most recently added bank account in your code will be the bank account at the end of the lists. You can access it by `name[-1]`, `age[-1]`, and `balance[-1]`. Negative indices in Python mean searching backwards so -1 gives you the last element of a list.

To search for an account you can do:

```
if y in name:
    found = name.index(y)
```

Then you can do `age[found]` and `balance[found]` to get the respective age and balance.

Comment: Thank you Thank you * 1000000000000000000000000000000. Now my problem is solved.Thank you so much.Thank you.Your answer is so helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you're adding new elements to the end of the list (ie `.appending()` them), you can `list[-1]` to get the last (therefore newest) element in the list.